# Best book for trigonometry and calculus?

Tags: secondary-education, book

I have completed my Maths textbook chapter trigonometry but still my textbook is not sufficient for  exam so if there is any suggestion regarding  trigonometry + calculus resource book pls feel free to suggest me thanks

Comment: I assume you are looking for a textbook that is "sufficient for exam."  Is that the primary criterion?  Can you be more specific about what is "sufficient for exam"?  If not, then I don't think anyone here can help you, we would just be guessing and our guesses would most likely be wrong.

Comment: I mean for higher education or higher competitive examinations @JRN

Comment: Why is your existing textbook not "sufficient for exam"?  How do we recommend textbooks to you when we don't know what you mean by "sufficient for exam"?  You should edit your question to contain all the relevant information.

Comment: If you are hoping to compete in mathematical competitions, check out Art of Problem Solving. Their precalculus includes trigonometry, and there's a calculus book also. https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/list/aops-curriculum

If this is not what you're looking for, please add detail to your question.

Comment: How is this book recommendation question different from the one from a day or two before that has +2? What books for trig and calc do you recommend? How is this unclear?

Comment: @Thierry: Are you referring to https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/17128/376? If you think this needs discussion, please feel free to bring it up on https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking I find the free books at [OpenStax Math](https://openstax.org/subjects/math) to be pretty comprehensive.

Comment: The OpenStax Math textbooks that I used a few years ago (Calculus) had many typographical errors.

Comment: thanks alot @Daniel R.Collins sir

Comment: @JRN: I guess I've most heavily used books up to College Algebra, but haven't seen widespread typos (and I tend to be an enormous OCD stickler for that). I do think the books evolve better all the time (fairly frequent updates).